# Rename folders with Wildcards

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-rename

I'm going through a large number of folders and files on my personal computer and trying to clean them up. I have a list of folders like this:

- Pictures of ABC
- Pictures of DEF
- Pictures of GHI With JKL
- MNO
- PQR
- ...

I would like to rename some of the folders to remove the leading characters of only those that start with "Pictures of" (or other strings as I find them). I have tried both `ren` and `move` commands in `cmd.exe` with no luck. The following is what I have tried:

- `ren "Pictures of"* *`
- `ren "Pictures of*" " *"`
- `ren "Pictures of*" "*"`
- `move "Pictures of*" "*"`
- `move "Pictures of"* *`
- `move "Picutres of*" *`

Thoughts?

Comment: are the extensions of the files the same? try using the extensions with your command

Comment: These are all directories that I'm trying to change.

Comment: It is likely that the new name will have spaces in it.

Comment: I'm trying this: `set check = "Pictures of"`
`for /d %D IN ("%check%*") do ren "%D" "%~nD_1"` This will add a _1. I'm wondering if a substitution might work, but have failed thus far. 
`for /d %D IN ("%check%*") do ren "%D" "%~nD:%check%="`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy to do in Windows PowerShell, so if you do not insist on using that outdated and outmoded Command Prompt, open PowerShell, navigate to the appropriate folder and issue the following commands:

```
Get-Childitem -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    $a=$_.Name
    $b=$a -replace "^Pictures of",""
    If ($a -ne $b) { Rename-Item $a $b }
}
```

I've tested this script in Windows PowerShell 5.1.